# Get a viz.json uri from a table name?

Tags: carto, carto-js

I am developing a web application that dynamically creates tables of data on CartoDB. Once I've uploaded some data, I'd like to show a cluster of points from that data. The uploaded data has a `the_geom` field of datatype `geometry` with well-identified data (eg, `ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(37.878086,-122.51026),4326)`)

So, given that I get a table name back from a successful create/write (eg, `t62b61b0091e633029be9332b5f20bf74_6d6d454828c05e8ceea03c99cc5f5`), I'd like to grab the `viz.json` identifier (eg, `2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5`, or even the full `https://myCartoAccount.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/2b13c956-e7c1-11e2-806b-5404a6a683d5/viz.json`) somehow, programmatically.

I can't seem to find the way to do this, nor references to it on the documentation.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`viz.json` files are related with Maps (visualizations) but not with tables (datasets).

The Import API will allow you to import a table and automatically create a Map from it (setting the `create_vis` parameter of the import request as true), and you will receive as a response the name of your new uploaded table as well as the visualization id which you can build to construct your viz.json URL as follows:

`https://$USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/$VISUALIZATION-ID/viz.json`

Here's a request example to upload a new table from a URL:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"url":"URL", "create_vis": true}' 
"https://USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v1/imports/?api_key=API_KEY"
```

The response of this request will give you "item_queue_id", which you can use in the next request.

This is the request to obtain the data of the result:

```
curl -v "https://USERNAME.cartodb.com/api/v1/imports/ITEM_QUEUE_ID?api_key=API_KEY"
```

And this will be an example of the response, where in the structure you can find the visualization ID that you need for your viz.json:

```
{"id":"ID","user_id":"USER_ID","table_id":null,"data_type":"url",
"table_name":null,"state":"failure","error_code":1002,
"queue_id":"QUEUE_ID,"tables_created_count":1,"synchronization_id":null,
"type_guessing":true,"quoted_fields_guessing":true,"content_guessing":false,
"create_visualization":true,"visualization_id":ID_HERE,
"user_defined_limits":"{\"twitter_credits_limit\":0}",
"get_error_text":[...]}%
```